# When I click to the next number on pagination, Link active still at number 1

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

My controller function

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_media');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $config['base_url']     = base_url()."secret/news/index";
        $config['total_rows']   = $this->news_media->getCount();
        $config['per_page']     = 3;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(4))?$this->uri->segment(4):0;

        $data = array();
        $data['allnews']    = $this->news_media->get($config['per_page'],$page);
        $data['links']      = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $html               = array();
        $html['title']      = "Setting";
        $html['head']       = $this->load->view('secret/template/header',null, true);
        $html['top']        = $this->load->view('secret/template/top',null, true);
        $html['menu']       = $this->load->view('secret/template/menu',null, true);
        $html['content']    = $this->load->view('secret/news/news',$data, true);
        $html['js']         = $this->load->view('secret/template/js',null, true);
        $this->load->view('secret/template/template',$html);
    }
}
```

Problem is that I have pagination 1,2 and in every page I display 3 items.
When I click second page link active still in number 1. How to fix its?

Thank before

Comment: what exact url you want on 2 page and your 3rd page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `uri_segment` in you pagination config settings:

```
$config['base_url']     = base_url()."secret/news/index";
$config['total_rows']   = $this->news_media->getCount();
$config['per_page']     = 3;
$config["uri_segment"]  = 4;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Hope this will help you to resolve this problem. Take a look on [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/pagination.html) that explain it.

> $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
>
> The pagination function automatically determines which segment of your URI contains the page number. If you need something different you can specify it.